# python create list from text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I have big text file and I want to read the file in python and save the data on list.
the structure of the file is like this

```
[{"address":"office1","id":"3311"},{"address":"office2","id":"3322"}]
[{"address":"office3","id":"3312"},{"address":"office4","id":"3323"}]
```

I want to save the first line in one list and the second line in different list. Can you please explain how to do it.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried and what the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**file.txt**

```
[{"address":"office1","id":"3311"},{"address":"office2","id":"3322"}]
[{"address":"office3","id":"3312"},{"address":"office4","id":"3323"}]
```

**code:**

```
import ast
lists = []
for line in open('file.txt'):
    lists.append(ast.literal_eval(line.strip()))

>>> lists
[[{'id': '3311', 'address': 'office1'}, {'id': '3322', 'address': 'office2'}], [{'id': '3312', 'address': 'office3'}, {'id': '3323', 'address': 'office4'}]]
```

Comment: [`eval` is evil](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/3001761)

Comment: @jonrsharpe no eval now

Comment: I would also have accepted https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: Thanks, i like it more. changed to ast.literal_eval

Comment: thank you it work like magic